# Unwanted White Space at the bottom of my website

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 589px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  right: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-shadow: 0px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b, 2px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b;
}


/* Menu*/
nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 210px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: #dc67e9;
  width: 1000px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 17%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bannerimage {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 589px;
}

.bannerpromo1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 500px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.bannerpromo2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 470px;
  margin-left: -780px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: #585656;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribebanner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  bottom: 430px;
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.subscribebannertext {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.howitworks {
  font-size:60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: #a8a8a8 4px 6px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 555px;
}

.subheaderbox1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  right: 315px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaderbox2{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 65px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaderbox3{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaders {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 275px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: -265px;
  word-spacing: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
}

.box1{
  position: relative;
  right: 370px;
  bottom: 225px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}
.box2{
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: 500px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}
.box3{
  position: relative;
  right: -405px;
  bottom: 780px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}

.step1{
  position: relative;
  right: 932px;
  bottom: 219px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.step2{
  position: relative;
  right: 546px;
  bottom: 493px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.step3{
  position: relative;
  right: 153px;
  bottom: 766px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  bottom: 660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  margin-left: -570px;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section2{
  position: relative;
  left: 149px;
  bottom: 660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section1title{
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.section1text{
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.section2title{
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.section2text{
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.imgsect1{
  margin-left: 148px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1660px
}

.imgsect2{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1668px;
  right: 571px;
}

.examples{
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1670px;
  right: 550px;
}
.examplesdesign1{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2580px;
  right: 320px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
}
.examplesdesign2{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1730px;
  right: 325px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SweetVie-Home-Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <style>
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topfiller"></div>

    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="90" alt="SweetVieLogo">
      <h2 class="subtitle">Vegan Baking Made Easy</h2>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="banner">
      <img class="bannerimage" src="images/mainpageimage.jpg" width="1414px" height="580px" alt="homepagebanner">
      <h2 class="bannerpromo1">Premium Packaged <br>Dessert Baking Kits</h2>
      <h2 class="bannerpromo2">High-quality,<br> organic and<br> vegan ingredients </h2>
      <div class="subscribebanner">
        <h3 class="subscribebannertext"> <a href="Subscribe.html" style="color: white"> SUBSCRIBE</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="howitworks">
      <h1>How It Works</h1>
      <div class="subheaderbox1"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox2"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox3"></div>
      <div class="subheaders">
        <h2>Click Prepare Enjoy</h2>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="box1" src="images/howitworks1.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step1">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step1">Select one of the three<br>subscription options</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box2" src="images/howitworks2.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step2">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step2">Get involved and play<br>with your food</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box3" src="images/howitworks3.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step3">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step3">Share or indulge in your<br>decadent and delicious treat</h3>

    <div class="section1">
      <h2 class="section1title">Food Time<br> Family Time</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section1text">Timeless family fun,<br> sharing special treats with the <br> special people you love </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
      <h2 class="section2title">The Next Step</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section2text">Health and desserts don't really<br> go together, with the exception of<br> SweetVie's sweets. Vegan desserts are the<br> baby steps you need for the best kind<br> of progress</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect1">
      <img src="images/homepagesection1.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="Food Time Family Time.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect2">
      <img src="images/homepagesection2.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="The Next Step.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="examples">
      <h2>Showcasing a collection of our most classic recipes</h2>
      <img src="images/dessertsarranged.jpg" width="900px" height="800px" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="examplesdesign1"></div>
    <div class="examplesdesign2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm confused as to why there is a large white space at the bottom of my website. I'm not too experienced with html/css, but I inspected the website's elements and it seems to be the div class'howitworks' that is creating the extra space.
I don't see a problem within the css styling of the div that could result this issue, but then again I'm very unfamiliar with the interactions between css properties and their respective elements. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post your code so we can examine it?

Comment: Please see how to [create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I keep posting before I inputting the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consistently using `position:relative` in conjunction with `bottom: length` in order to reposition your elements.

The above method ***only repositions the rendered layer of your element*** not the actual element in DOM. Which means that, technically, your element is still at the same position it was before applying `bottom` to it, so it occupies the same space.

The quick and dirty fix for it would be to <strike>give the last of your elements a big negative bottom margin, to make up for the extra space.</strike>
On second thought, the fastest way to fix it would be to replace all `bottom: value` with `margin-top: -value`.

Here's how your layout looks with `bottom`s replaced with negative top margins:

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 589px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  right: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-shadow: 0px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b, 2px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b;
}


/* Menu*/
nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 210px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: #dc67e9;
  width: 1000px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 17%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bannerimage {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 589px;
}

.bannerpromo1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -500px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.bannerpromo2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -470px;
  margin-left: -780px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: #585656;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribebanner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  margin-top: -430px;
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.subscribebannertext {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.howitworks {
  font-size:60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: #a8a8a8 4px 6px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 555px;
}

.subheaderbox1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  right: 315px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaderbox2{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
  left: 65px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaderbox3{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -200px;
  left: 450px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.subheaders {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -275px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: -265px;
  word-spacing: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
}

.box1{
  position: relative;
  right: 370px;
  margin-top: -225px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}
.box2{
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  margin-top: -500px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}
.box3{
  position: relative;
  right: -405px;
  margin-top: -780px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}

.step1{
  position: relative;
  right: 932px;
  margin-top: -219px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.step2{
  position: relative;
  right: 546px;
  margin-top: -493px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.step3{
  position: relative;
  right: 153px;
  margin-top: -766px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  margin-left: -570px;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section2{
  position: relative;
  left: 149px;
  margin-top: -660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section1title{
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.section1text{
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.section2title{
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 70px;
}
.section2text{
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.imgsect1{
  margin-left: 148px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1660px
}

.imgsect2{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1668px;
  right: 571px;
}

.examples{
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1670px;
  right: 550px;
}
.examplesdesign1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2580px;
  right: 320px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
}
.examplesdesign2{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1730px;
  right: 325px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SweetVie-Home-Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <style>
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topfiller"></div>

    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="90" alt="SweetVieLogo">
      <h2 class="subtitle">Vegan Baking Made Easy</h2>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="banner">
      <img class="bannerimage" src="images/mainpageimage.jpg" width="1414px" height="580px" alt="homepagebanner">
      <h2 class="bannerpromo1">Premium Packaged <br>Dessert Baking Kits</h2>
      <h2 class="bannerpromo2">High-quality,<br> organic and<br> vegan ingredients </h2>
      <div class="subscribebanner">
        <h3 class="subscribebannertext"> <a href="Subscribe.html" style="color: white"> SUBSCRIBE</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="howitworks">
      <h1>How It Works</h1>
      <div class="subheaderbox1"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox2"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox3"></div>
      <div class="subheaders">
        <h2>Click Prepare Enjoy</h2>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="box1" src="images/howitworks1.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step1">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step1">Select one of the three<br>subscription options</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box2" src="images/howitworks2.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step2">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step2">Get involved and play<br>with your food</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box3" src="images/howitworks3.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step3">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step3">Share or indulge in your<br>decadent and delicious treat</h3>

    <div class="section1">
      <h2 class="section1title">Food Time<br> Family Time</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section1text">Timeless family fun,<br> sharing special treats with the <br> special people you love </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
      <h2 class="section2title">The Next Step</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section2text">Health and desserts don't really<br> go together, with the exception of<br> SweetVie's sweets. Vegan desserts are the<br> baby steps you need for the best kind<br> of progress</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect1">
      <img src="images/homepagesection1.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="Food Time Family Time.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect2">
      <img src="images/homepagesection2.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="The Next Step.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="examples">
      <h2>Showcasing a collection of our most classic recipes</h2>
      <img src="images/dessertsarranged.jpg" width="900px" height="800px" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="examplesdesign1"></div>
    <div class="examplesdesign2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

But this, along with how you've built your layout is not a good design practice (especially because you don't know how much you need make up for, as your elements will likely have different heights on different devices). You'll therefore have considerable problems displaying the contents reasonably on devices of various widths or devices with variable width (think rotating a phone or a tablet).

A better approach would be to rethink your layout, probably to use containers/sections and allow the contents to occupy their space in DOM and size their parents accordingly.

---

Note: the `position:relative; left|top|bottom|right: length;` is a technique intended for animations, specifically because it doesn't actually move the actual element from DOM, **thus** not triggering re-renders on subsequent elements in DOM, making animations very light on the browser (which doesn't need to repaint the rest of the document at each frame). It's not a technique intended for layouts.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to html and css and was confused with the properties "padding" and "margins" when it seemed like using the position: relative was an easier method to achieve what I wanted. Now, however, I do see how its complicates things.

Comment: I tried to add a negative bottom margin to my last few elements but it website continues to remain the same. Is there an alternative method, or perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly? It's **margin-bottom: -(value)px;**,  isn't it?

Comment: It's quite alright. It's the only way to learn. You've asked a good question and now you know more on how `position` works. You probably want to use `display` (flex) to position elements side by side, along with `justify-contents`, `align-items` and also playing with `margin` values.

Comment: I added the code statements to see where my elements are actually located. I think for now I'll just try to manually re-position the bottom values of each element, but thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually, I think the fastest way to fix it would be to replace all `bottom: length` cases with `margin-top: -length;`. But it's still a very bad solution. Try to view your layout on a different device and you'll understand why. It's not something that's easily fixable.